# Is Java's BigDecimal the closest data type corresponding to C#'s Decimal?

Tags: c#, java, decimal, bigdecimal, complex-data-types

According to the chart [here](http://java.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/data-types-interoperability-between-net-and-java), the equivalent data type in Java to C#'s `Decimal` is `BigDecimal`.

Is this really so? What's up with the "Big" preamble? There doesn't seem to be a "SmallDecimal" or "LittleDecimal" (let alone "MediumSizedDecimal") in Java.

I must say, though, that chart was the clearest thing I found on the subject; the other links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java#Advanced_numeric_types) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/820-1072/ahigz/index.html) were about as clear to me as the Mississippi River after a torrential tempest.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep - that's the corresponding type.

Since you are using Java after C# - don't be too surprised to find little nuances like this - or be too upset when there is no easy way to do something that's "easy" to do C#. The first thing that comes to my mind is int & int? - in Java you just use int and Integer.

C# had the luxury of coming after Java so lots of (what I subjectively see as) bad decisions have been fixed/streamlined. Also, it helps that C# was designed by [Andres Hejlsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) (who is arguably one of the best programming language designers alive) and is regularly "updated" unlike Java (you probably witnessed all things added to C# since 2000 - [complete list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions))

Comment: Good point on the nullable int in Java being integer. I agree on Hejlsberg - he deserves a spot on the Mt. Rushmore of geeks. I still wonder why it's called "Big" decimal, though - big in relation to what?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I can only speculate, but my guess is that it's named BigDecimal since it's for "Big Decimals". More here - http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/Java-Data-Type/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.htm

Comment: There is a good reason why it is called out as "Big". See my answer for details.

Comment: Now, as for Java being "regularly updated", I note that Java did just undergo a major revision and as a result it now has *many* of the features of C# 2.0.

Comment: @EricLippert I hope they keep going with "updating" ;). I would love to see var in Java the way it's implemented in C# - it would help a lot with declaring instancing of all those Class.Subclass that are very common in Java (or at least in Android)

Answer (score 33):

> Is this really so?

They are similar but not identical. To be more specific: the Java version can represent every value that the C# version can, but the opposite is not true.

> What's up with the "Big" preamble?

A Java `BigDecimal` can have *arbitrarily* much precision and therefore can be *arbitrarily large*. If you want to make a `BigDecimal` with a thousand places of precision, you go right ahead.

By contrast, a C# `decimal` has a fixed size; it takes up 128 bits and gives you 28 decimal places of precision.

To be more precise: both types give you numbers of the form

```
+/- someInteger / 10 ^ someExponent
```

In C#, `someInteger` is a 96 bit unsigned integer and `someExponent` is an integer between 0 and 28.

In Java, `someInteger` is of arbitrary size and `someExponent` is a signed 32 bit integer.

Comment: Another major difference is that by default, `BigDouble` will either perform math exactly or throw an exception when it cannot.  By contrast, `Decimal` will silently round off decimal digits which it cannot handle.  For example, when dividing 1 into 536870912, Java's `BigDecimal` will compute the value as 0.00000000186264514923095703125 while .NET's `Decimal` will compute it as 0.0000000018626451492309570312D.

Comment: @supercat `BigDouble`? where did that come from? did you mean `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @MauricioMorales: Mea culpa.  Yeah, `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

The C# Decimal and java BigDecimal types are **not** equivalents. BigDecimal is arbitrary precision. It can literally represent any number to any precision (until you run out of RAM).

C# Decimal is floating point but "fixed length" (128 bits). Most of the time, that's enough! Decimal is **much** faster than BigDecimal, so unless you really need a lot of precision it is a superior option.

What you probably want for Java is https://github.com/tools4j/decimal4j or a similar library.